# Jena Fuseki Vs Virtuoso

Tags: jena, semantic-web, virtuoso, fuseki, linked-data

I am running same queries on Virtuoso and Jena Fuseki - A query on Virtuoso gave `ResultRows=594890` while on Fuseki it gave the error of "page not responding". Also in many other cases, the fuseki could not execute the same queries which were done by virtuoso efficiently. I am wondering how could I adjust the `MaxQueryExecutionTime`, `ResultSetMaxRows`, `MaxQueryCostEstimationTime` in Fuseki, as it can be done in Virtuoso by editing the `virtuoso.ini` file.

Example Query below gave the above mentioned no. of results in Virtuoso but it failed on Fuseki.

```
PREFIX rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX bench: <http://localhost/vocabulary/bench/> 
PREFIX swrc:  <http://swrc.ontoware.org/ontology#> 
SELECT ?article WHERE {
       ?article rdf:type bench:Article .
       ?article ?property ?value
       FILTER (?property=swrc:pages)
}
```

Comment: Try to improve your question with some query examples....

Comment: "page not responding" is not an error from Fuseki - it is the browser probably. The request is still executing at the server.

Comment: Timeouts can be set in the Fuseki configuration. https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-configuration.html

Comment: Worth noting, your query is much less efficient than if you replace `?article ?property ?value FILTER (?property=swrc:pages)` with `?article swrc:pages ?value`. Making this change may radically decrease the timeout(s) required for your existing query, in either SPARQL engine.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @AndyS,

Fuseki timeouts can be set in the Fuseki configuration, [as documented](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-configuration.html).